# Выгрузка данных с файла (php)

Tags: php

Нужна помощь
Встречал ссылки типа:
site.ru/promo/3883
site.ru/promo/9594
В файлах "3883","9594" хранятся данные, которые затем присваиваются переменным в файле promo.php
Как можно организовать подобную систему?

Answer (score 1):

ссылки типа `/promo/xxx` с помощью .htaccess (если у вас апач) перенаправляются в ваш скрипт `promo.php`

```
RewriteRule ^/promo/(\d+)  promo.php?pid=$1 [L]
```

в скрипте вы получаете `$pid = $_GET['pid']`;

потом на основании данного идентификатора вы строите путь к файлу, И инкулдите его, возвращая результат в переменную

```
$configFilename = WWW_ROOT . "/config/$pid.php"
if(file_exists($configFilename){
    $config = include $configFileName;
}

print_r($config);
```

при этом ожидается, что в файле будет контент вида

```
<?php
    return [
          'param' => "value",
          ....
       ];
```

Если надо загрузить значения прям в переменные, то `extract($config)` в помощь.
Если конфиг этот у вас не пхп файл, а какой-нибудь txt, то читаете его аналогичным образом и потом разбираете как надо.

Answer (score 0):

1. Файлы "3883", "9594" должны иметь в себе примерно следующее:

   ```
   <?php

   $vars = [
       'nameOfVar1' => 'valueOfVar1',
       'nameOfVar2' => 123456789,
       'nameOfVar3' => false
   ];
   ```
2. Далее, в своем коде вы должны определить путь к целевому файлу и можете воспользоваться функцией extract, она разберет ваш массив и создаст из него переменные с именами, которые были в качестве ключей и их значениями.

Получится примерно следующее:

```
<?php

$path = $this->getPathToTargetFile();

require_once($path);

extract($vars);

var_dump($newOfVar2); // Отобразит значение (int) 123456789
```

Ссылки для ознакомления:

1. [include](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.include.php)
2. [extract](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.extract.php)